# Question in proof from James Milne's Algebraic Number Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, algebraic-number-theory

I'm having difficulty understanding a step in a proof from J.S. Milne's Algebraic Number Theory ([link](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ANT.pdf)). Here $\zeta$ is a $p$th root of unity and $\mathfrak p = (1-\zeta^i)$ for any $1\leq i\leq p-1$ is the unique prime ideal dividing $(p)$, and it's been assumed that $p$ does not divide $x, y,$ or $z$.

> LEMMA 6.9 The elements $x+\zeta^iy$ of $\mathbb Z[\zeta]$ are relatively prime in pairs.
>
> PROOF. We have to show that there does not exist a prime ideal $\mathfrak q$ dividing $x+\zeta^iy$ and $x+\zeta^jy$ for $i\neq j$. Suppose there does. Then $\mathfrak q\mid ((\zeta^j-\zeta^i)y) = \mathfrak py$ and $\mathfrak q\mid ((\zeta^i-\zeta^j)x) = \mathfrak px$. By assumption, $x$ and $y$ are relatively prime, and therefore $\mathfrak q = \mathfrak p$.
>
> > Thus $x+y \equiv x+\zeta^iy\equiv 0 \mod \mathfrak p$.
>
> Hence $x + y\in \mathfrak p\cap\mathbb Z=(p)$. But $z^p=x^p+y^p\equiv x+y=0\mod p$
>   which contradicts our hypotheses.

My problem is in the middle line which I have isolated. Why is there an $i$ such that $x+\zeta^iy\in\mathfrak p$?

Comment: If $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal and $a_1...a_n \in \mathfrak{p}$ then $a_i \in \mathfrak{p}$ for some $i$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the question. But isn't the assumption that $\mathfrak{q}\mid x+\zeta^iy$? And we just concluded that $\mathfrak{q}=\mathfrak{p}$, so $x+\zeta^iy\in\mathfrak{q}=\mathfrak{p}$. This holds for the $i$ produced by the contrapositive assumption. Also, if it holds for one choice of $i$ it holds for all of them given that all the differences $(\zeta^i-\zeta^j)y\in\mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: Thank you, I seem to have had a very silly misunderstanding that this $i$ was different from the one before. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the assumption (to be contradicted) there is *some* prime $\frak{q}$ that divides $x+ \zeta^i y$ and $x+\zeta^j y$. In particular $\frak{q}$ divides $(x+ \zeta^i y)$, which is to say $x+\zeta^i y \in \frak{q}$. The first part of the proof shows $\frak{q}$ has to be $\frak{p}$.